# Laravel Excel - Only returns first column of row

Tags: php, excel, laravel-4, maatwebsite-excel

I'm trying to import Excel-data by Laravel Excel (http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs). I'm using Laravel 4.2.

But i only get the first column of the row in the result, seems strange to me, and I get figure out why.

```
Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load("fileName.xlsx", function($reader) {
    $reader->skip(14);
    dd($reader->first());
});
```

I get this result:

```
object(Maatwebsite\Excel\Collections\CellCollection)#19057 (2) {
  ["title":protected]=> NULL ["items":protected]=> array(2) {
    ["flik_1_personal"]=> string(7) "Annika " [0]=> NULL
  }
}
```

Since the Excel-file looks lite this (the row):
[image]

I expected to get all the cells however this is not the case. Does anyone know why this is happening?
Thanks!

**Update**
Looks like it's because I don't have any "headers" for the other cells (except first name, which is shown in the result). Is there a setting for getting the cells value, without "headers"?

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($file, function($reader) {

            foreach ($reader->toArray() as $row) {
                                            $bb[] = $row;
                                        }
            echo '<pre>';print_r($bb );echo '</pre>';  die();


        });
```